# Detecting particular objects in the image i.e image segmentation with opencv

Tags: iphone, image-processing, opencv, image-segmentation

I have to select any particular object visible in my image on i-phone.
Basically my project is to segment image objects on the basis of my touch.

The method I am following is to first detect contours of the image and then select a particular sequence based on finger touch.
Is there any other method which would be more robust because I have to run it on video frames?

I am using OpenCV and iphone for the project.
PLease help if there is any other idea which has been implemented or is feasible to implement.

Comment: So what you want is to select any given object by touching your iPhone's video feed and keep it selected? Could you give more details on your project? Is the camera moving, what kind of object, do you have prior information before selecting, what will you do with selected object, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at SIFT or SURF implementations? They both track object features and are resilient (to a certain degree) to rotation, translation and scale.

Also check out FAST which is a corner detection algorithm which might help you, they have an app on the app store showing how quick it is too.

Comment: had read about SIFT and SURF but i am not sure that it would help me selecting an object with fingertouch on iphone.

Comment: What you would do it define a region where the touch was and generate a SIFT feature set from it, from that point you are tracking instances of that 'set'