# iOS: Decompose UIImageView image into shapes and change their colors

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, shapes, image-segmentation

I have been making an iPhone App where I need to identify and decompose different shapes(e.g Wall, Chair, Book, etc..) in UIImageView's image and change their color. So far I have implemented code to allow user to select color and apply it to selected area (pixel base) using gesture recogniser but what I am looking for is far more than what I have done!

Is it posible to detect the different shapes available in given image and change their color?

Thanks.

Comment: This problem is called **Image Segmentation**, and is an active research area in Computer Vision.  You will find many papers on the subject, and some sample code, but nothing you can drop into your app in five minutes.  Any really good algorithms will probably be too slow for current iOS devices.  If someone does have an algorithm that is good enough, fast enough and easy to import, expect to pay appropriately.  Type "image segmentation" into the search engine of your choice and prepare for a lot of reading.

Comment: Sounds like these guys are discussing something relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405109/detecting-particular-objects-in-the-image-i-e-image-segmentation-with-opencv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

whatever algorithm you use, you should place it on top of one of the best frameworks for computer Vision, [open CV for iOS](http://code.google.com/p/opencv-ios/)

then you might check other projects in other languages that do this image segmentation using open cv, and with the theory may be roll your own solution ;)
good luck

Answer (score 1):

Object recognition and detection is a very wide topic in computer science and, as far as I know, is not supported by UIImage's public methods. I think you have a long way to go in order to achieve your goal. Try and look up any open source iOS projects that handle object detection or maybe even look into non-native libraries that have iOS wrappers, such as openCV. Good luck, don't give up.